# If I select specific country exit nodes, why is IP not dynamic anymore?

Tags: exit-relays

I'm trying to look like I am coming from a small country, and when I do that, no matter how many times I press "New Tor circuit for this site", my final, exit IP stays the same. Why does this happen?
Can I have dynamic IP but from a certain country?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that this small country only has one exit node. Or only one exit node with an exit policy that allows what you're doing.

By choosing a country with only one exit, you restrict your possible exits to a set of only one, so every circuit you build will use this one exit.

If you go to the bottom of this page: https://torstatus.blutmagie.de/ you can:

- Sort Router Listing By: Country code
- Sort Order: Ascending
- Bad Exit, Hibernating: No
- Exit, Running, Valid: Yes
- Apply Options

That will show you all good exits by country.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that there is indeed only one...
Is there perhaps any other way to make it seem like I'm from specific country and to keep it dynamic?

p.s. is there an option for me to contact you directly/privately?

Comment: By choosing a country with only one exit, you restrict your possible exits to a set of only one, so every circuit you build will use this one exit. (<-- Added this to answer.) I've seen comment threads being turned into chats, but I think only moderators can do that. Those are not private, but prevent cluttering up questions and answers.